# What is required for seasonal maintenace of a heat pump?

Tags: furnace, heat-pump

Over the years I've had several local HVAC companies provide seasonal maintenance of the heat pumps and propane furnace in my house.  It seems that every technician--even within the same company--does different things.  One tested a capacitor.  Another hosed out the compressors outside.  Some open the air handler up and vacuum it.  They all clean the burners, check/clean the filters, and make sure the condensation drain is clear.  What should they be doing each visit?

Comment: The variation in tasks might be explained by indications the technician observes:  dirty indoor coils?  Clean them.  Noisy outdoor fan?  Clean and lubricate.  Or it could be differences in training and company philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is pretty good.  Check/clean flame, filters, condensation drain and coils.  I would also listen for abnormal noise and check both cooling and heating performance by measuring the indoor and outdoor temperature splits.  I would not go measuring capacitors unless I suspected a failure.